# how to highlight separately

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to highlight the errors of the fix message sent from client side.
However, when doing so it will not follow this algorithm. If there is an error in the fix message which is just a string, it will highlight the entire string, otherwise it will just leave it unhighlighted.
Basically what I'm asking is how do I highlight multiple parts, rather than highlighting the entire output once there is an error?

for example:
The error I'm getting

```
no error - unhighlighted
error - highlighted
no error - highlighted
no error - highlighted
no error - highlighted
error - highlighted
```

what I want:

```
no error - unhighlighted
error - highlighted
no error - unhighlighted
no error - unhighlighted
no error - unhighlighted
error - highlighted
```

problem area

```
if(outputLine.equals("No errors")) {
    tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
    lengthH += (inputLine+"\n\n\n").length();
}
else {
    tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
    int pos = inputLine.indexOf(inputLine, 0);
    int len = lengthH;
    lengthH += (inputLine+"\n\n\n").length();
    h.addHighlight(len, lengthH+(inputLine+"\n\n\n").length(),
                                DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
}
```

Program

```
Highlighter h =  tfFIXMsg.getHighlighter();
try {             
    int lengthH = 0;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
        tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");

        if (inputLine.trim().equals("Bye.")) {
            System.out.println("Exit program"); 
            break;
        }

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
        Scanner input4 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));

        String csvline = getCsvLineVal(getLocation34CSV(
                getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV(parseFixMsg(
                    inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(
                        inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,input2)),
                                            getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
        outputLine = compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV(parseFixMsg(
                inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(
                    inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

        out.println(outputLine);

        if(outputLine.equals("No errors")) {
            tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
            lengthH += (inputLine+"\n\n\n").length();
        }
        else {
            tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
            int pos = inputLine.indexOf(inputLine, 0);
            int len = lengthH;
            lengthH += (inputLine+"\n\n\n").length();
            h.addHighlight(len, lengthH+(inputLine+"\n\n\n").length(),
                                    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        }

        input1.close();
        input2.close();
        input3.close();
        input4.close();
}
```

Comment: If no decent answer in the near future, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: and this could be overkill with JTextArea, use JTextPane

Comment: I'm guessing that Loedolff's answer hasn't helped you. If so, then again (and sorry to sound like a broken record), if you're still stuck, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `(inputLine+"\n\n\n").length()` twice to lengthH.  You should probably do that just once?  Also, it doesn't look like lengthH is properly initialized when the 'else' block executes?